# Is there any invariant that is preserved when you change the underlying field of a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory

> If you change the field you change the vector space.
>   The vector space is defined by the triad: field + set + operations, if you change one of these (in your case *field*), you change the space, so you can not have an endormorphism.

I am in this hypothetical vector space over A complex field which there is a passage or 'transition' *from* this complex field *into* a real field

Complex Field $\rightarrow$ Real Field

I'm not interested to change the vector space but seems that is not possible if you change field because you change vector space if you change field. 
Is there any invariant that is preserved when you change the underlying *field* of a vector space ?

What should be preserved, what operation or structure emerges if we pass from the **vector space over a complex field** to a **vector space over real field** or viceversa?

Comment: You cannot "change field" in such generality. What you can do is constructing a complex vector space if you are given a real one; this is called *complexification*. The opposite operation can be done in greater generality; if you are given fields $F_1\subset F_2$ then an $F_2$ vector space can be regarded as a $F_1$ vector space. (For example, any complex vector space is also a real vector space). That's all you can do.

Comment: So when I "change field" is it really the very definition of a field that must be preserved? I read that for complexification we need to set a relation between *field extension and its subfield* or  about *morphism of rings*, but..this is an generic Ring homomorphism or is it something more specific (inner automorphism, endomorphism..)? For realization or decomplexification how *removes the possibility of complex multiplication of scalars* ?

Comment: And if I want to change from a *real* field to *rational* field we need to talk about *rationalization* ? Inverse process from rational field to real field is a sort of realization but not like a decomplexification ?

Comment: I ask about "how removes the possibility of complex multiplication of scalars" because I read that *When the underlying ring is commutative, for example, the real or complex number field, these two multiplications are the **same**, and are simply called scalar multiplication*. $\rightarrow$ It gives me the impression that here is removed the *scalar multiplication* itself ***before***, not only that *"removes the possibility"* of complex multiplication of scalars **then**

Comment: I have a hard time following what you wrote, it is very complicated. These things should be easy; if you have a complex vector space, it is obviously also a real one; if you have a real one, it is also obviously a rational one, and this is true for all fields which include a subfield. That's it. Complexification is a different operation, that is tailored to complex numbers.

Comment: How is called operation to 'downgrade' from real numbers to rational numbers ? And opposite operation to 'upgrade' rational numbers to real numbers ? Yes, the numbers are the same but between real & rational numbers are a field? real *field* I remember is not equal to rational *field*, is correct ?

Comment: I don't know. Besides, these are separate questions and with every comment you produce a lot more of them, so I am overwhelmed and I cannot answer. May I suggest opening another thread, asking these questions in a well-organized manner.

Comment: ok, thanks, I find this, maybe is the answer about real & rational, so I see that key is still *field extension* - You approve ?